# Laravel - custom name while uploading image using storage

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

I am trying to upload a file using laravel Storage i.e

`$request->file('input_field_name')->store('directory_name');`

but it is saving the file in specified directory with random string name.

Now I want to save the uploaded file with custom name i.e

`current/badge-group-${badge_group_id}/badge-${badge_id}/${imageName}`

with actual file name. What is the fastest and simplest way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files

You can act on the file in the request object directly and then call `storeAs()` to specify a filename

```
$request->file('input_field_name')->storeAs('directory_name');
```

Comment: Route::get('/photo/badge-group-{badge_group_id}badge-{badge_id}/{imageName}',
function(){
        return "success";
});

Comment: class ImageTestController extends Controller
{
    public function index($badge_group_id){
      \Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory('path/to/'.$badge_group_id);
    }
}

Comment: What am I looking at here?